# How to add a new row in a combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox, row, pocketpc

I developed a Pocket PC app.
It works but i wanna add a new (without data) row in a combobox:

```
      SqlCeCommand sql3 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT (ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL + '~' + ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL) AS NUM_EMPL FROM ACM_EMPL INNER JOIN ACM_ACT ON ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL = ACM_ACT.NUM_EMPL WHERE (ACM_ACT.NUM_ACTIVO = '" + oc.Text + "'AND ACM_ACT.NUM_CIA = '" + CIA.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.NUM_TIPO = '" + TIPO.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.SUB_NUM_ACT = '" + SUBNUM.Text + "') ", conn);
        sql3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlCeDataAdapter cb3 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql3);
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        cb3.Fill(dt3);
        foreach (DataRow dr3 in dt3.Rows)
        {
            ma.cmbEmpleado.SelectedValue = dr3["NUM_EMPL"].ToString();
        }
```

It shows: [image]

I wanna add a "-select-" or a "     "   Row, how could i do it? i tryed with

```
    dt3.Rows.Add("----------");
```

and things like these, but it doesnt work!.

Thank you

Comment: Right before you load the ComboBox or Bind it.. add this line of code 
`cb3.Add("-select-");`

Comment: Let me try @DJKRAZE! Thank you so much!

Comment: Where in your code did you place the code to add the new row? When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the row was not added to the DataTable?

Comment: I had it before the `foreach`, and after `cb3.Fill(dt3);` @field_b

Comment: @Jean I have identified problem in my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
            SqlCeCommand sql3 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT (ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL + '~' + ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL) AS NUM_EMPL FROM ACM_EMPL INNER JOIN ACM_ACT ON ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL = ACM_ACT.NUM_EMPL WHERE (ACM_ACT.NUM_ACTIVO = '" + oc.Text + "'AND ACM_ACT.NUM_CIA = '" + CIA.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.NUM_TIPO = '" + TIPO.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.SUB_NUM_ACT = '" + SUBNUM.Text + "') ", conn);
        sql3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlCeDataAdapter cb3 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql3);
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        cb3.Fill(dt3);
        if (dt3.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            ma.cmbEmpleado.DataSource = dt;
            ma.cmbEmpleado.DataValueField = dt3.Columns["NUM_EMPL"].ToString();
            ma.cmbEmpleado.DataTextField = dt3.Columns["NUM_EMPL"].ToString();
        }
        ma.cmbEmpleado.Items.Insert(0, "---------");
        ma.cmbEmpleado.Items[0].Value = "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SqlCeCommand sql3 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT (ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL + '~' + ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL) AS NUM_EMPL FROM ACM_EMPL INNER JOIN ACM_ACT ON ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL = ACM_ACT.NUM_EMPL WHERE (ACM_ACT.NUM_ACTIVO = '" + oc.Text + "'AND ACM_ACT.NUM_CIA = '" + CIA.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.NUM_TIPO = '" + TIPO.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.SUB_NUM_ACT = '" + SUBNUM.Text + "') ", conn);
    sql3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlCeDataAdapter cb3 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql3);
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    cb3.Fill(dt3);
    foreach (DataRow dr3 in dt3.Rows)
    {
        ma.cmbEmpleado.Items.Add(dr3["NUM_EMPL"].ToString());
    }
    ma.cmbEmpleado.Items.Insert(0, "------------");
    ma.cmbEmpleado.SelectedIndex = 0;

    cb3.Dispose();
    dt3.Dispose();
```

Obs: ma.cmbEmpleado.Items.Add(INDEX, TEXT);

Comment: I tried it @user3666315, it doesn´t work: `El valor no está dentro del intervalo esperado.`

Answer (score 1):

Add the row to the DataTable and then bind the table to the ComboBox by setting its properties like this:

```
  SqlCeCommand sql3 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT (ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL + '~' + ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL) AS NUM_EMPL FROM ACM_EMPL INNER JOIN ACM_ACT ON ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL = ACM_ACT.NUM_EMPL WHERE (ACM_ACT.NUM_ACTIVO = '" + oc.Text + "'AND ACM_ACT.NUM_CIA = '" + CIA.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.NUM_TIPO = '" + TIPO.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.SUB_NUM_ACT = '" + SUBNUM.Text + "') ", conn);
    sql3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlCeDataAdapter cb3 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql3);
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    cb3.Fill(dt3);

DataRow row = dt3.NewRow();
row[0] = "";
dt3.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
cmb.DisplayMember = "NUM_EMPL";
cmb.ValueMember = "NUM_EMPL";
cmb.DataSource = dt3;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: In your code you are calling `sql3.ExecuteNonQuery()` which is not required when you are about fill data adapter.

Use a valid connection string in the under-mentioned code:

```
string sQuery = @"SELECT (ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL + '~' + ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL) AS NUM_EMPL FROM ACM_EMPL INNER JOIN ACM_ACT ON ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL = ACM_ACT.NUM_EMPL WHERE (ACM_ACT.NUM_ACTIVO = '" + oc.Text + "'AND ACM_ACT.NUM_CIA = '" + CIA.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.NUM_TIPO = '" + TIPO.Text + "' AND ACM_ACT.SUB_NUM_ACT = '" + SUBNUM.Text + "') ";
string sConnectionString =  @"Data Source = C:\Program Files\" +
    @"Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Samples\" +
    @"Northwind.sdf";

using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(sConnectionString))
{
     SqlCeCommand sql3 = new SqlCeCommand(sQuery, conn);       
     SqlCeDataAdapter cb3 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql3);
     DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
     cb3.Fill(dt3);

     foreach (DataRow dr3 in dt3.Rows)
     {
        ma.cmbEmpleado.Items.Add(dr3["NUM_EMPL"].ToString());
     }

     ma.cmbEmpleado.Items.Insert(0, string.Empty);
     ma.cmbEmpleado.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Note: code not tested. Also example connection string is used.

Comment: Let's try it! Thank you @Hassan Nisar